# move files based on a keyword/separator to a terget folder of that keyword name (create folder if it does not exist)

Tags: python, powershell

I have multiple files of various extensions like .csv, .pdf, .xml, .txt, .xlsx and so on.
Files are either in a format of abc.xyz.com_xxxx.extension or abc_xxxx.extension.
(The file names are basically subdomains.domain_sometool.extension. for eg a nikto scan on a url like register.google.com would give me file name such as register.google.com_nikto.txt/csv/xml or it migth be saved as register_nikto.txt/csv/xml)

What i want to do is move each file into its subdomain directory. for eg abc.xyz goes into a folder named abc, pqr.abc goes into a folder named pqr.
If a subdirectory exists then it should be moved into that and if it does not exist a new directory shall be created for that subdomain.

Solutions in python, bash or powershell will be appreciated.

I have the following code from one of the other stack overflow questions.
I would like a code which does similar thing for all types of extensions at once.

```
for i in *_*.txt; do 
    fp="${i/_?*/}"
    mkdir "$fp" 2>/dev/null # ignore errors else this will complain for 2nd etc files
    mv "$i" "$fp"
done
# do remaining .txt files, with no "_"
for i in *.txt; do 
    fp="${i/.txt/}"
    mkdir "$fp" 2>/dev/null # ignore errors else this will complain for 2nd etc files
    mv "$i" "$fp"
done
```

Comment: Where should `abc.xyz.pqr.com_xxx.ext` go to? To `abc` or to `abc.xyz` ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin it would always go to the topmost subdomain so ```abc.xyz.pqr.com_xxx.ext``` would ideally go to abc but in my test cases i only have 2 levels of subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell you could do something like this:

```
# define extensions to process
$extensions = -split '.csv .pdf .xlsx .xml .txt .otherExtesions .etcetera'

# switch location to relevant folder
Set-Location path\to\folder\with\files

# iterate over all files in folder, filter for extensions
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *_*.* |Where-Object Extension -in $extensions |ForEach-Object {
  # grab the first DNS label from the file name
  $label = $_.Name -split '[._]' |Select -First 1

  # test if target folder exists, otherwise create it
  if(-not(Test-Path -LiteralPath $label)){
    New-Item -Name $label -ItemType Directory |Out-Null
  }

  # move file to target folder
  $_ |Move-Item -Destination $label
}
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for the help. The script is doing what its supposed to, only thing is if there is a space in a file name such as "Screenshot (10)", "Screenshot (11)" and so on it is making a folder for each screenshot as well. I could only move renamed files in the source directory i know but for knowledge base if we're splitting only at "-split '[._]'" these two characters why is the space getting put into a folder of ots own as well?

Comment: Splitting on either `.` or `_` will have no effect on a string that doesn't contain either - `$label` just becomes the original string up until the `.` before the extension :) I've updated my answer to filter the files with `*_*.*` <-- this way it'll simply ignore files without the expected `_` in the name

Comment: @Ken Excellent, you're most welcome! Please mark my answer "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left (or accept one of the other answers if they answer your question better) :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the target subfolder name is derived from the first part of the file's name, separated from the rest of the name by either a dot (`.`) or an underscore (`_`).

In PowerShell you could do this:

```
$sourcePath      = 'X:\TheSourceDirectory'
$destinationPath = 'Y:\RootPathForTheSubDirectories'
# get a list of all files, except '.ps1' script files
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -File | Where-Object {$_.Extension -ne '.ps1'}
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $targetFolder = Join-Path -Path $destinationPath -ChildPath (($file.BaseName -split '[._]')[0])
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $targetFolder -PathType Container)) {
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetFolder -ItemType Directory
    }
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $targetFolder
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the script, this is working as well. Only thing is it moves itself in a fodler of its own in the target directory as well. Maybe we could add a check to compare the filename to whatever we set the ps1 filename to be and then skip it if that fiel name is detected?

Comment: @Ken I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment.. The question was about creating new folders (if they do not yet exist) and then move the file in there based on the first part of the filename wasn't it? Or do you mean the script is also in the directory where the files to be moved are ?

Comment: @Ken If you mean that you have also placed the script file itself in that source directory and want to exclude it from being moved, then please see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

Using `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.*_*.*; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    dir=${file%%.*}
    mkdir -p "$dir" && mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```